# LabVIEW Asynchronous call

Tags: labview

I have two VIs. The first VI (AsynchronousCall.vi) performs an "asynchronous call." (see in the following picture)
[image: AsynchronousCall.vi]
The following VI (Test.vi) is started by the asynchronous call. (see in the following picture)
[image: Test.vi]

The first VI only iterates over an array and starts the Test.vi. An element from the array is passed. This element should then be used in Test.vi. However, the first entry from the array is not passed correctly after the first call.
It follows that my asynchronous program does not receive the correct input data.

**Important:** In order to recreate the Senario, the front panel of Test.vi can be opened first after the asynchronous call. Because when it's open, it works as intended!
The target/actual comparison is in the following list:

**Target value**

1. Asynchronous program should have "Test_0" as input parameter.
2. Asynchronous program should have "Test_1" as input parameter.
3. Asynchronous program should have "Test_2" as input parameter.
4. Asynchronous program should have "Test_3" as input parameter.

**Actual value**

1. Asynchronous program is "" (empty string) as input parameter.
2. Asynchronous program is "Test_1" as input parameter.
3. Asynchronous program is "Test_2" as input parameter.
4. Asynchronous program is "Test_3" as input parameter.

[image: Test_Data]

How can it be avoided that the string is empty the first time it is called?

The 32-bit version of LabView 2015 is used, but this Senerio also occurs with newer versions (32-Bit LabVIEW 2019)

Comment: This would be unexpected behaviour but to try and find out what is going wrong could you wire a string indicator to your test VIs input with the indicator inside the while loop. Also add a small delay in the loop to avoid consuming a full CPU core. How are you ensuring the stop button starts with a false value? Finally, what is the execution mode of the VI - re-entrant or non re-entrant?

Comment: For my test, the execution mode is "Non-Renetantrant", but in the right code the execution mode is "Preallocated clone reentrant"

Comment: I added delays in several places, but didn't bring anything. Also changed the data type to Variant or Cluster.... All to no avail.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this only happens when the the front panel of Test.vi can be opened first after the asynchronous call. Because when it's open, it works as intended!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have LabVIEW infront of me to verify things but you can set Test.VI to show it's front panel when called which might help for this test case.

Comment: I did, but then it works.  For my application, however, I do not want the front panel to appear

Comment: Assuming I have understood your comments correctly and want to launch multiple clones of a re-entrant VI then you need to change the open VI ref options flag from 0x80 to 0xC0 which is the original 0x80 bitwise added to 0x40 "Enable simultaneous calls on reentrant VIs". Your current test Vis will not stop automatically so you will need to modify them or you might have difficulty stopping them without closing LabVIEW

Answer (score 1):

When you call a VI asynchronously with the Front Panel closed, LabVIEW does not appear to update the values displayed in the controls - this makes sense from a resource perspective as why paint an update to a control that no one can see?

If you were to perform an operation on the passed value in your test VI - such as writing it to a file or some shared queue you should be able to verify that the correct value is indeed passed, just not displayed in control on the front panel. The one button dialog can also be used for debugging this but it might block the `open VI reference` call in the launcher VI and thus cause your launcher loop to stall. See [this discussion on LAVA forums](https://lavag.org/topic/18243-lv-dialog-box-holds-open-vi-reference/?do=findComment&comment=109353) about the root loop and the built-in dialog windows.